# Mismatch between array sizes when doing cv2.absdiff()

Tags: python, opencv

After I added this part of code which is related to cropping frames, I got error:

```
frame = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

the error is:

line 71, in press_it
delta_frame = cv2.absdiff(first_frame,gray)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:650: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'cv::arithm_op'

this is my complete code:

```
def press_it():

            first_frame = None
            status_list = [None,None]
            times = []
            startTime=datetime.now()
            print(startTime)
            #Dataframe to store the time values during which object detection and movement appears | "C:/Users/mojta/Desktop/videos/pred.mp4"
            df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Start','End','Duration'])
            cam = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
            length = int(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
            print(length)
            y=50
            x=50
            h=100
            w=200
            #Iterate through frames and display the window
            while cam.isOpened():
                check, frame = cam.read()
                length-=1
                frame = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                #Status at beginning of the recording is zero as the object is not visisble
                status = 0

                #Converting each frame into gray scale image
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

                #Convert grayscale image to GaussianBlur
                gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21,21), 0)

                #This is used to store the first image/frame of the video
                if first_frame is None:
                    first_frame = gray
                    continue

                #Calculates the difference between the first frame and another frames
                delta_frame = cv2.absdiff(first_frame,gray)

                #Giving a threshold value, such that it will convert the difference value with less than 30 to black
                #If it is greater than 30, then it will convert those pixels to white
                _,thresh_delta = cv2.threshold(delta_frame, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
                thresh_delta = cv2.dilate(thresh_delta, None, iterations=3)

                #Defining the contour area i.e., borders
                cnts,_ = cv2.findContours(thresh_delta.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

                #Removes noises and shadows, i.e., it will keep only that part white, which has area greater than 10000 pixels
                Acuraccy = acuraccySlider
                for cont in cnts:
                    if cv2.contourArea(cont) < Acuraccy:
                        continue
                    #Change in status when the object is being detected
                    status = 1
                    #creates a rectangular box around the object in the frame
                    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cont)
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 3)
```

Comment: `(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cont)` This changes the value of x, y, w, and h. When you change the values of w and h, you change the size of the window you are cropping. When you change the size of the window you are cropping, it is not the same size as the `first_frame` variable. Then you get that error.

Comment: cv2.absdiff(first_frame,gray). Both are same color. Should be cv2.absdiff(frame, gray)